# Chrome DevTools : Html element hover not working

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I have this problem for some time, my chrome devtools have a strange behaviour. The hover and highlighting elements don't work for some obscure reason.
Please see the gif below, when I unfold a particular element, it will break the devtool.
I don't really understand where this is coming from. I compared the settings with a friend, we have the same...

Thank you in advance for the answers :)

[Example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9srfd.gif)

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome/Chromium. Use an older/newer version of the browser.

Comment: I have the Version 99.0.4844.82 (Official Build) (64-bit). My friend have the same version and it's working fine for him...

Comment: It's a bug that depends on some condition and no one knows what it is last time I checked.

Comment: @IceCrew I'm having the same issue with the same version as you

Comment: I had the same problem but on a Mac. It appears if you zoom out the Elements tab, that's when the hover stops working. The solution is to restore the original zoom or higher.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I´ve been crazy with this and finally found a solution:

Just doing Zoom in on the Elements Tab (Ctrl + mouse scroll wheel) and it will start working again   :'-)

Comment: Thank you for this little hack, it's working FINALLY !

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: Not working - maybe they changed their code

Comment: It did not work