# Hover effects not working? Keyboard navigation works though

Tags: html, css, hover

I am making a website and this problem popped up where my hover effects stop working and the keyboard navigation works fine. Just not the hover effects.

I tried remaking the hover effects. That didn't work.

```css
.login {
  width: 6em;
  height: 2.5em;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -9rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.login:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.login:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.get {
  width: 10em;
  height: 3.3em;
  background-color: #0072D1;
  color: #E4E4E5;
  border: 1px solid #0072D1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.get:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.4);
}

.get:focus {
  filter: brightness(1.4);
}

.watch {
  width: 7.5em;
  height: 3.3em;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #E4E4E5;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.watch:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.watch:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="/" class="get">GET DISNEY-</a>
  <a href="/" class="watch">TRAILER</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to see the hover visuals just fine. Maybe it's an issue with your browser/environment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585772/chrome-devtools-html-element-hover-not-working

Comment: I pasted your code into a stack snippet and it appears to work fine

Comment: I am using Replit and the webview in that the hover effects aren't working so I realize that it may be a browser thing. Thanks for the help with testing on your own.